# Determining if I have wifi (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: wireless, wifi-hardware-switch

I am not sure whether my motherboard has wifi built-in.
I see no indication of wifi in `iwconfig`. Does that indeed mean no wifi hardware is available?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Check the output of the following command to view hardware info:

```
lspci -v
```

Answer (score 1):

`lshw` is the command to use.

```
$ apt-cache search lshw  
lshw - information about hardware configuration  
lshw-gtk - graphical information about hardware configuration
```

`man lshw` says, in part:

```
NAME
   lshw - list hardware

...  

DESCRIPTION
   lshw is a small tool to extract detailed information on the hardware configuration of the machine. It can report exact memory config‐
   uration, firmware version, mainboard configuration, CPU version and speed, cache configuration, bus speed, etc. on DMI-capable x86 or
   IA-64 systems and on some PowerPC machines (PowerMac G4 is known to work).

   It currently supports DMI (x86 and IA-64 only), OpenFirmware device tree (PowerPC only), PCI/AGP, CPUID (x86), IDE/ATA/ATAPI,  PCMCIA
   (only tested on x86), SCSI and USB.
```